# How do I load an AudioBuffer with Angular $http?

Tags: angularjs, web-audio-api

I am getting started with the Web Audio Api to experiment a little with it wanted to see how best to work with it in AngularJS.

Other Web Audio stuff I have tried seems to work in Angular, such as creating a web audio sine wave etc, but I am just not sure of the best way to load audio in angular, if I then want to be able to manipulate it with the Web Audio API

I naively tried to put some functions directly into a AngularJS Controller which doesn't seem right - code below.

In the Chrome Dev Tools Network tab I can see the test.mp3 that should load notifies 'Failed to load response data'. However the path to the file is correct, and if I click on this in the dev tools the file opens up and starts playing.

Any help is greatly appreciated

```
// Controller and attempt to load audio
(function () {
'use strict';

angular
    .module('app')
    .controller('mvMainCtrl', mvMainCtrl);

mvMainCtrl.$inject = ['$resource', '$scope', '$http' ];

function mvMainCtrl($scope, $http, $resource) {


var ctx; //audio context 
var buf; //audio buffer 

//init the sound system 
function init() { 
  console.log("in init"); 
try { 
    ctx = new AudioContext(); 
    loadFile(); 
} catch(e) { 
    alert('you need webaudio support'); 
} 
} 


function loadFile() { 
  var req = new XMLHttpRequest(); 
  req.open("GET","/app/main/sounds/test.mp3",true); 
req.responseType = "arraybuffer"; 
req.onload = function() { 
    //decode the loaded data 
    ctx.decodeAudioData(req.response, function(buffer) { 
        buf = buffer; 
        play(); 
    }); 
}; 
req.send(); 
}


  loadFile();


 function playback() {
    var playSound = ctx.createBufferSource();
    playSound.buffer = buf;
    playSound.connect(ctx.destination);
    playSound.start(audioContext.currentTime);
 }


  playback();



 }
})();
```

Comment: Welcome to SO, Jamie! Great to hear that you're interested in Web Audio! There's rule of thumb that questions shouldn't be too broad and that you should include code that you've tried so far to solve your issue. This seems like it might break both those points as it is indeed broad and the code provided is not web audio + angular, but rather generic web audio code. It seems like the basic question is "How do I load an AudioBuffer with Angular $http", which is a good succinct question. I'd recommend you rephrase and streamline your question, which will help us provide better answers. Cheers!

Comment: More info on good questions can be found here: http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic (And it's a good idea to read up, there's folks who's really quick to downvote questions that they don't think fit the bill - not a nice experience).

Comment: Thanks Oskar! I was so careful to make sure the question wasn't already here but didn't think about making it more more clear - will make some changes.

Comment: and sorry for shamelessly ripping off your question suggestion...I couldn't think of anything better!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just had the same problem and after a couple of hours spent on this issue, I finaly found a way to get it work:

**Promise style:**

```
$http({
    method: 'GET',
    url: url,
    responseType: 'arraybuffer'
}).then(function(response) {
    audioContext.decodeAudioData(response.data, function(buffer) {
        mainBuffer = buffer
    }, function(err) {
        console.log(err)
    })
})
```

**Standard style:**

```
$http({
    method: 'GET',
    url: url,
    responseType: 'arraybuffer'         
}).success(function(data) {
    audioContext.decodeAudioData(data, function(buffer) {
        mainBuffer = buffer
    }, function(err) {
        console.log(err)
    })
})
```

With `XMLHttpRequest()`, the file was corrupt, and the *responseType* attribut should be specified as *arraybuffer*.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an implementation of a BufferLoader you can use to load an array of sound files:

```
// BufferLoader
function BufferLoader(context, urlList, callback) {
  this.context = context;
  this.urlList = urlList;
  this.onload = callback;
  this.bufferList = new Array();
  this.loadCount = 0;
}

BufferLoader.prototype.loadBuffer = function(url, index) {
  // Load buffer asynchronously
  var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
  request.open("GET", url, true);
  request.responseType = "arraybuffer";

  var loader = this;

  request.onload = function() {
    // Asynchronously decode the audio file data in request.response
    loader.context.decodeAudioData(
      request.response,
      function(buffer) {
        if (!buffer) {
          alert('error decoding file data: ' + url);
          return;
        }
        loader.bufferList[index] = buffer;
        if (++loader.loadCount == loader.urlList.length)
          loader.onload(loader.bufferList);
      },
      function(error) {
        console.error('decodeAudioData error', error);
      }
    );
  }

  request.onerror = function() {
    alert('BufferLoader: XHR error');
  }

  request.send();
}

BufferLoader.prototype.load = function() {
  for (var i = 0; i < this.urlList.length; ++i)
  this.loadBuffer(this.urlList[i], i);
}
```

How you can use it to load sounds:

```
var sounds = ["assets/test.mp3", "test2.mp3"]
var context = window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext || window.MozAudioContext || window.mozAudioContext;

var loader = new BufferLoader(context, sounds, onComplete);

var audioBuffers;
function onComplete(bufferList){
  console.log("Sounds loaded!");
  audioBuffers = bufferList;
}

function playSound(i){
  // create buffer source node which is used to play a sound one time
  var bufferSourceNode = context.createBufferSource(); 
  // set buffer to one of the loaded sounds;
  bufferSourceNode.buffer = audioBuffers[i];
  // connect to output
  bufferSourceNode.connect(context.destination);
  // play the sound
  bufferSourceNode.start()
}
```

Now to play a sound you have to call:

```
playSound(0); // play first sound in array of loaded sounds
```

---

In your example I don't see where the `play()` function is defined that you call in `decodeAudioData`. You probably wanted to call `playback()`. Also you call playback on Controller initialization where the sounds are not yet loaded, which you shouldn't do.

Comment: thanks for this. I was still interested in how to do it with $http service which should allow a response type of array buffer, but this is certainly cleaner than my attempt - thanks!