# Load a sound file as arrayBuffer in Ionic

Tags: ionic-framework, buffer, web-audio-api

Try a lot of things before asking, but I still failed to load a sound as buffer in my Ionic project.

I don't know if this is a bug from my old firefox browser 26 (Fedora 18) or if I am doing it wrong.
Here my code, pretty much classic for loading arrayBuffer for web audio API with XMLHttpRequest():

```
var request = new XMLHttpRequest()  
      request.open('GET', './sound/mySound.ogg', true)
      request.responseType = 'arraybuffer'      
      request.onload = function() {
        audioCtx.decodeAudioData(request.response, function (buffer) {
          mainBuffer = buffer
        }, function (err) {
            console.log(err)
        })
      }
  request.send()
```

I get this warning message in console:

> Les données passées à decodeAudioData possèdent du contenu de type
>   inconnu.

and *err* is undefined

Same piece of code works fine in an Apache server.
What am I missing here?
I try also something like this:

```
$http.get(url, { responseType: 'arraybuffer' }).success(function (data) {
    audioCtx.decodeAudioData(data, function (buffer) {
    mainBuffer = buffer
}, function (err) {
    console.log(err)
})
}, function (err) {
    console.log(err)
})
```

But still no luck. The file seems corrupted.  So frustrating...

html5 *audio* tag returns the same error.

Is it a problem with the Ionic server?
Is there a way to solve this issue ?
Any advice would be very appreciate.

Answer (score 2):

Just found a solution to my problem and make an answer to this similar question:
[How do I load an AudioBuffer with Angular $http?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34019824/how-do-i-load-an-audiobuffer-with-angular-http/36267539#36267539)

Answer (score 0):

Based on the error message, it seems that your browser doesn't support ogg files.  Try a different compression method for your audio file.

Comment: This is the same with _wav_ or _mp3_ files. Also, I can play _ogg_ file with Apache server. Thanks anyway.

Comment: In fact, you're right. There is a problem with ogg files on my system. I just can't decode file type: _Ogg data, FLAC audio_ but no problem with _Ogg data, Vorbis audio_ or _FLAC_ files. I still digging.